# Take a natural quotient of context-free grammars

Tags: fl.formal-languages, context-free

Fix a finite alphabet.

Let $\mathrm{CFG}$ be the set of context-free grammars on this alphabet, $\mathrm{CFL}$ the set of context-free languages, $\mathrm{UG}$ the set of unrestricted grammars and $\mathrm{REL}$ the set of recursively enumerable languages.

Then we almost have a commutative square $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{CFG}\times\mathrm{CFG} @>{?}>> \mathrm{UG}\\
@V{\mathrm{generate}\times\mathrm{generate}}VV @VV{\mathrm{generate}}V\\
\mathrm{CFL}\times\mathrm{CFL} @>{\mathrm{quotient}}>> \mathrm{REL}
\end{CD}
except one map. Is there a natural choice for the missing map?

Comment: What is the "quotient" map on the bottom of the square?

Comment: @D.W. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_a_formal_language